# Facebook Ads in InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

How to display Facebook Ads in InAppBrowser.

I tried with plugin cordova-plugin-facebookads, its not working. 
Ie., No error but its not displaying any ad.
Is there a way to display ads in inappbrowser?

Comment: its working android 
first install plugin  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebookads` after  see html file code [see here](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads/blob/master/test/index.html)

Comment: It works in webview. Whether same works in InAppBrowser? I'm facing issue in InAppBrowser/

Comment: its not support InAppBrowser

Comment: But I'm seeing few apps are able to display ads in inappbrowser.. there may be some workaround